# Shutdown the system using C does not work

Tags: c, windows, shutdown

I am trying to explore the things that we can do using `system()` call in C.
Following is the code that I used to shutdown my machine. It worked on Windows XP, but does not work on my machine when I boot in Windows 7. What must be the issue?
I have tried `system("shutdown -R Now")` on openSUSE 11.3 and it works fine there as well. What causes this platform issue in here? I am not much familiar with `system()` related routines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)    
{    
   char ch;    

   printf("Do you want to shutdown your computer now (y/n)\n");    
   scanf("%c",&ch);    

   if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')    
      system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown -s");    

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you running the program from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: No Sir. I tried this on win-bash

Comment: Are you starting this program from your compilator?
What compilator are you using?

Comment: You need to run the program from a context that has permission to shut the system down. For Windows 7, that would be an elevated command prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am trying to explore the things that we can do using system() call in C.

There is no exploring required: you can do anything that you can do from the command line. Whatever arguments you pass to `system` are basically "typed" at the command line. But that's precisely why you should *avoid this function* at all costs! It's insecure, it's slow, there's no reliable way of handling errors, and there's almost always a better way of accomplishing what you want.

This case is a good example. Using `system` to invoke `shutdown.exe` is not the right way to programmatically shut down Windows. There's an API call for that: [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868.aspx). The `uFlags` parameter is used to indicate whether you want the system to logoff the user that owns the process calling the function, restart the system, or power down the system.

You use it from C like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>  // need this to call Windows APIs

int main(void)    
{    
   char ch;    

   printf("Do you want to shutdown your computer now (y/n)\n");    
   scanf("%c",&ch);    

   if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
      ExitWindowsEx(EWX_POWEROFF, 0);

   return 0;
}
```

Of course, just like with invoking `shutdown.exe` using `system`, the application will need the appropriate permissions in order to be able to initiate a system shutdown. Simply speaking, you will need to be running the app with administrative privileges. [Like David suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483361/shutdown-the-system-using-c-does-not-work#comment25409099_17483361), from an elevated command prompt. The linked documentation for the `ExitWindowsEx` function has more details on the security model if you're interested.

The obvious criticism is that `ExitWindowsEx` is platform-specific. You can't call this function on a Unix-based machine because it is not implemented. You'll need to call the appropriate POSIX API (or whatever it is on your platform). If you truly want to write platform-independent code, that requires you to use conditional compilation (i.e. `#if` statements) that detect the target OS and invoke the appropriate APIs, which is ugly.

The problem is, the `system` function has exactly that same limitation. Whatever arguments you pass are executed as if you'd typed them into the command line. And the command line environment in different operating systems is very different. It's simply a coincidence if both Windows and some other operating systems have a `shutdown` command. And even then, it's not likely to work identically. So you're still left with ugly platform-dependent code. You might as well call the *right* system APIs.

The main use of the `system` function is that it allows you to launch another application from your own application. But there is an API function for that, too: [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx). It's much more powerful, accepting various arguments to control exactly how the launched process should behave. And most importantly, it provides a standardized way of reporting and handling errors.

Oh, and, **hard-coding paths is always wrong**, whether you're using `system`, `CreateProcess`, or a lowly batch file. The system drive might not be "C". Windows might not be installed in a directory named "Windows". And on and on. This is another benefit of calling the appropriate OS APIs: they don't require hard-coding paths or special knowledge of the default command prompt environment (i.e. the path).

Comment: In the default configuration, Windows does not require you to have administrator privilege to shut down the machine.

Comment: I have no idea, I don't think there's any such thing as a "default configuration of Windows". I guess we're assuming non-server SKUs? And are you sure that limited users can shut down the system? That's part of a "default configuration" from my perspective.

Comment: Specifically, you must have the "Shut down the system" user right in order to shut down the system.  In client SKUs this is granted to the Users group (as well as to Administrators and Backup Operators) by default.  ("By default" in this case meaning "unless someone has changed it", i.e., this is the setting that Windows ships with.)

Answer (score 1):

for Windows XP Use

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown -s");
```

for Windows 7

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\shutdown /s");
```

for Ubuntu

```
system("shutdown -P now");
```

If you are using Turbo C Compiler then execute your file from folder. Press F9 to build your executable file from source program. When you run from within the compiler by pressing ctrl+F9 it may not work.

Comment: Why would anyone still be using a 23 year old DOS compiler?

Comment: Both Windows XP and 7 support `/` and `-` for command line switches. Why are you suggesting a different syntax? (And what happens if Windows is not installed on drive C?)